# How to sum the values of the column in postgresql on a certain condition?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table, that looks something like this:

```
Name    | Val_Num
--------------------
Joey    | 1
Joey    | 2
Chandler| 2 
Monica  | 3
Monica  | 2
```

What I need is to make a select in which I'll remove from duplicates in names and sum up the values in Val_Num (but the sum up should use simple formula - if value is 1 add 1, if value is not 1 add 0.5).

Result of the query should look like this:

```
Name    | Val_Num
--------------------
Joey    | 1.5
Chandler| 0.5 
Monica  | 1
```

Looking forward for your help, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the results you are showing. If I add up the values plus 1 or 0.5 respectively as you say, I get: Joey = (1 + 1) + (2 + 0.5) = 4.5 ; Chandler = (2 + 0.5) = 2.5 ; Monica = (3 + 0.5) + (2 + 0.5) = 6

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You must have gotten me wrong or I wasnt clear enough - I didnt mean to add, I meant to change the values - if theres a 1, then keep the 1. But of theres not 1, then change the value to 0.5. And after that sum up. So, if Joey has 1 and 2, those values should change to 1 and 0.5 and then sum up to 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression in order to decide when to add 1 and when 0.5.

```
SELECT Name, SUM(CASE WHEN Val_Num = 1 THEN Val_Num ELSE 0.5 END)
FROM test_table
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE WHEN` statement to replace all values that are not 1 with 0.5, and then do a simple GROUP BY query

```
select name, sum(case when val_Num !=1 
    then 0.5 else val_Num end 
) from table_1 group by name
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=029f04317a9dceee907b361c1a00265f)